# MailApp limit from Google appscript trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

It seems the [limit of 100/day for MailApp](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z131vllyenqfwr5py04ccz1b3uqpcn4q5so0k?cbp=3lxyzdmpvfa6&sview=1&cid=5&soc-app=115&soc-platform=1&spath=/app/basic/stream&sparm=cbp%3Dhsszp5dtcw9h%26sview%3D1%26cid%3D5%26soc-app%3D115%26soc-platform%3D1) is also applied to add-on script (even those of the store). Is there any way to increase it, on add-on or at user side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limits apply to all scripts, even add-ons. There's only one way to increase it, which is use [Google Apps for Business](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/). As you can see from the [Quota dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard) under 'Quota limits', the limit for Google Apps for Business users is 1500 Email Recipients/day.

Alternatively, this is a recipient limit, so if you're sending the same message to several recipients,  you could utilize a service such as [Google groups for Business](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en#groupsforbus) to limit the amount addresses you send to, thus avoiding hitting the quota.

**Slight Edit:** To answer your below query, I believe it's the domain installing the script that needs to upgrade for a higher quota, but I've never confirmed. You can check how much quota a user has left by using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota() in the script, so that might help you with your troubleshooting.

Comment: Are speaking of Google Apps for Business on user side or on script side? Who should subscribe?

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified that above, and added additional possibly helpful info.